# how to download image of a particular year from google static maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I know how to download images from google static maps API. But I want to know how to download satellite images for a particular year like 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible.

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7950

However, Google didn't share any ETA for this feature request. You can star the public issue to let Google know that you are interested in the feature request and to get further updates.

Comment: Is it possible to download them from some other place??

Comment: I'm not aware about such possibility.